# Python package not found in jupyter even after running pip install

Tags: python, numpy, package, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I want to use `numpy` in my Jupyter notebook. However, I came across a weird problem. Despite the fact that:

1. I have a `numpy` installed in my default `python3`.
2. From Jupyter I've run a command `!pip install numpy` and `!pip3 install numpy`.
3. I restarted my `notebook` multiple times.

After running a command `import numpy` I get a message that package is not found:

> ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

I use `python3` kernel of course.

Has anyone come across similar problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try installing `numpy` (or any other package for that matter available on `pip`) directly from your `jupyter` cell.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

Please see Jake's [tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If the package is installed sucessfully, you can add the path where the package is located either as an environment variable or in your notebook.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/anaconda3/envs/gdd/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if it is in the 'bin' folder. Alternatively, add the the path to numpy in the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip3 install numpy --user
```

This installs the library to your home directory.